# Image gets displayed when inside hidden div

Tags: css

This has got to be simple but I can't see my mistake.

I have a div with an image inside it. The div has the style display:none. The div disappears, but the image stays put. Here's the plunk:

http://plnkr.co/edit/R3i7GZKOiiSvEj3vEuIE?p=preview

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style type="text/css">
      #loading {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0px;
        left: 0px;
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        background: white;
        opacity:0.2;
        filter:alpha(opacity=20); /* For IE8 and earlier */
        overflow: hidden;
      }

      .centered {
        position:absolute;
        top: 50%;
        left: 50%;
      }

      .hide {
        display:none;
      }
    </style>
  </head>

  <body>

  <div id="loading hide">
    <img class="centered" src="http://www.woldsvets.co.uk/runnerapeman.gif" width="60px" border="0"/>
  </div>

  </body>

</html>
```

Why doesn't the image also get hidden when inside an hidden element?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the wrong HTML. It should be:

```
<div id="loading" class="hide">
```

In your CSS, you have rules for `#loading` and `.hide`. Your HTML, `<div id="loading hide">`, has an ID that's invalid because of the space. You probably meant to have the HTML I suggest above. [plinkr example](http://plnkr.co/edit/nSE6G12XyrhLHKSSCjx9?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

Your `.hide` class should be either a class in the markup, or an ID in your css.

Answer (score 0):

You have two ids. Either use classes or a single id